# Find the path to a file when part of the location is known

Tags: c#

I am fairly new to C# and could use some help figuring out how to find a file's path when I know part of the path - I am trying to find a log file installed by another app, that will always be in a set part of the tree even in a custom install.

e.g.

/Main/Bin/Logs/logfile.log

I need to load this path into a variable so I can reference it when building a zip file later.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you tried anything? Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: can you be more specific also state whether this is `WinForms. WPF, Asp.NET, etc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the filename and the root of part of the path, you can recursively search all the folders underneath that root path using [`Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462.aspx)

For example:

```
string root = "Some root directory name";
string filename = "Some filename";

foreach (var directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(root, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string fullPathName = Path.Combine(directory, filename);

    if (File.Exists(fullPathName))
    {
        // Now you can return or store fullPathName 
    }
}
```